# How to Set File Path in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, filepath

I cannot figure out or find examples for how to set a file path, in terms of the appropriate formatting.

```
    -- set up the attachment folder path
    tell application "Finder"
        **set folderName to "License Agreements" as text**
        **set homePath to "~/Desktop/Uber Drive/UOT - EchoSign" as text**
        set attachmentsFolder to (homePath & folderName) as text
    end tell
```

I want set the path to ~/Desktop/Uber Drive/UOT - EchoSign but am really struggling to find any examples, and I've spent quite a while shooting around in the dark. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop shooting in the dark...

```
-- You don't need a "Finder" block
set folderName to "License Agreements"
set homePath to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "Uber Drive/UOT - EchoSign"
set attachmentsFolder to homePath & "/" & folderName
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Will try this when I get back to the office, hope it works. Happy New Years @adayzdone!

Comment: Thanks adayzdone! Your answer is correct, although it still does not work due to a Mail Applescript error in Maverick and Yosemite (http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/automatically-save-attachments-in-mail-app/) :(

Comment: The reason it is not working is because you need to save attachments in your downloads folder. Then move them wherever you want.